# How to use truncate of text helper inside html(tag) helper in view of cakephp?

Tags: cakephp-2.1

echo $this->Html->tag('span',$user['User']['user_title'], array('class' => "nameOfUser");

###
in this  tag i want to  truncate user_title to 20 characters .
SO how i can used truncate in HTML tag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the TextHelper; http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/text.html#texthelper

```
echo $this->Html->tag('span',
    $this->Text->truncate($user['User']['user_title'], 20),
    array('class' => "nameOfUser")
);
```